# What does "xargs grep" do?

Tags: command-line, grep, xargs

I know the `grep` command and I am learning about the functionalities of `xargs`, so I read through [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/xargs-examples) page which gives some examples on how to use the `xargs` command.

I am confused by the last example, example 10. It says "The xargs command executes the grep command to find all the files (among the files provided by find command) that contained a string ‘stdlib.h’"

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | xargs grep 'stdlib.h'
./tgsthreads.c:#include
./valgrind.c:#include
./direntry.c:#include
./xvirus.c:#include
./temp.c:#include
...
...
...
```

However, what is the difference to simply using

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | grep 'stdlib.h'
```

?

Obviously, I am still struggling with what exactly xargs is doing, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question may be helpful: [When is XArgs needed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/when-is-xargs-needed)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | grep 'stdlib.h'
```

This pipes the output (stdout)* from `find` to (stdin of)* `grep 'stdlib.h'` *as text* (ie the filenames are treated as text). `grep` does its usual thing and finds the matching lines in this text (any file names which themselves contain the pattern). The contents of the files are never read.

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | xargs grep 'stdlib.h'
```

This constructs a **command** `grep 'stdlib.h'` to which each result from `find` is an argument - so this will look for matches **inside** each file found by `find` (`xargs` can be thought of as turning its stdin into arguments to the given commands)*

Use `-type f` in your find command, or you will get errors from `grep` for matching directories. Also, if the filenames have spaces, `xargs` will screw up badly, so use the null separator by adding `-print0` and `xargs -0` for more reliable results:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'stdlib.h'
```

*added these extra explanatory points as suggested in comment by @cat

Comment: you might consider noting (because it seems you omitted) the key point that `|` pipes **stdout** to grep's **stdin** which is not the same as grep's arguments and gives confusing results.

Comment: Or use GNU find's `find -name '*.c' -exec grep stdlib.h {} +`.  I pretty much never actually use xargs.  Also surprised nobody mentioned that xargs serves a similar purpose to `grep $(find)` command substitution, so I wrote an answer of my own.  Explaining xargs as command substitution with fewer limitations and problems seems natural.

Comment: One situation I use xargs on is if I am deleting a lot of files as a result of find.  If you just do -exec rm, it will run rm on each file one at a time, which is very inefficient.  Piping to xargs will do them all at once with one rm.  Limiting with say -n50 (do 50 at a time) could prevent command line overflow (problem with a lot of files).

Comment: @lsd: Why not `find -delete` for that special case?  Or for commands other than `rm`, if you have GNU find, then `-exec some_command {} +` groups into batches like xargs, instead the `\;` behaviour of running the command separate for each.

Comment: @lsd `find` runs command on each file if and only if it's using `-exec command \;` Both `xargs` and `-exec command \+` will call the command with maximum number of arguments allowed by the system. In other words, they're equivalent

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have a habit sometimes of not using gnu extensions because I used to use other systems that didn't have the gnu tools.  I have had a problem with command line arguments too long with xargs without putting a limit, but that was some time ago and the behavior may have changed since then.

Answer (score 8):

**xargs takes its standard input and turns it into command line args.**

`find . -name '*.c' | xargs grep 'stdlib.h'` is very similar to

```
grep 'stdlib.h' $(find . -name '*.c')  # UNSAFE, DON'T USE
```

And will give the same results as long as the list of filenames isn't too long for a single command line.  (Linux supports megabytes of text on a single command line, so usually you don't need xargs.)

---

But both of these suck, because **they break if your filenames contain spaces**.  Instead, `find -print0 | xargs -0` works, but so does

```
find . -name '*.c' -exec grep 'stdlib.h' {} +
```

That never pipes the filenames anywhere: `find` batches them up into a big command line and runs `grep` directly.

`\;` instead of `+` runs grep separately for each file, which is much slower.  Don't do that.  But `+` is a GNU extension, so you need `xargs` to do this efficiently if you can't assume GNU find.

---

**If you leave out `xargs`, `find | grep` does its pattern matching against the list of filenames that `find` prints.**

So at that point, you might as well just do `find -name stdlib.h`.  Of course, with `-name '*.c' -name stdlib.h`, you won't get any output because those patterns can't both match, and find's default behaviour is to AND the rules together.

Substitute `less` at any point in the process to see what output any part of the pipeline produces.

---

Further reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ has some great stuff.

Comment: GNU xargs also has `-d` to set the separator, so you can use `-d'\n'` to handle a newline-separated list, which may be useful if you handle a list of file names in a file, etc. (as long as the file names don't have newlines in them, that is.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: yeah, newlines in filenames are a lot more rare than spaces, since they break most scripts.  `myfunc(){ local IFS=$'\n'; fgrep `stdlib.h` $(find)`; }` also works with the same effect.  Or as a one-liner, a `(IFS=...; cmd...)` subshell also works to contain the change to IFS without having to save/restore it.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Please don't do `command $( find )` type of stuff. Problematic filenames with spaces and special characters can break this type of thing.   At the very least double quote the command substitution.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Thanks for pointing out that it looks like I'm actually recommending doing that.  People skimming might have copy/pasted that instead of reading the next section.  Updated to address that.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Or were you replying to my comment?  Notice that I set `IFS` so it's equivalent to using `xargs '-d\n'`.  Glob expansion and shell metacharacter processing happens before command substitution's effects, so I think it's safe even with filenames that contain `$()` or `>`.  Agreed that using word-splitting on command substitution is not good practice except for one-off interactive use where you know something about the filenames.  But `command "$(find)"` is only useful if you expect it to produce exactly 1 filename...

Comment: @PeterCordes I was actually referring to the example in the answer. Setting `IFS` also has its own issues, because its possible to have filenames with `\n` in them.  For instance,`touch with$'\n'newline ; IFS='\n' fgrep 'stdlib.h' $(find) ` and `touch with$'\n'newline ; IFS='\n' fgrep 'stdlib.h' "$(find)" ` still produce errors

Comment: `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep 'stdlib'` is by far the best option. That or `find -type f -exec fgrep 'stdlib' {} \+ `. In any case, the point is that when you use `$()` you rely on shell to properly pass filenames, which doesn't work out property because there's many things to consider. When you use `xargs` and `-exec` ,  that's  being handled `find` or `find` and `xargs` alone, so the shell plays almost no role there.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy:   I completely agree with you; if you think my answer is giving the wrong impression to beginners, please suggest how to fix it, or just edit it yourself (I might roll-back some of it, though).  I know filenames can contain newlines.  See my answer, and [my first comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833128/what-does-xargs-grep-do/833190?noredirect=1#comment1271501_833190).  Agreed that messing around with IFS or using `xargs '-d\n'` is not the best approach for this.  But it can be useful for interactive use if you know what filenames you're running it on.

Answer (score 6):

In general, `xargs` is used for cases where you would pipe (with the symbol `|`) something from one command to the other (`Command1 | Command2`), but the output from the first command is not correctly received as the input for the second command.

This typically happens when the second command does not handle data input through Standard In (stdin) correctly (eg: Multiple lines as input, the way the lines are setup, the characters used as input, multiple parameters as input, the data type received as input, etc..). To give you a quick example, test the following:

**Example 1:**

`ls | echo` - This will not do anything since `echo` does not know how to handle the input he is receiving. Now in this case if we use `xargs` it will process the input in a way that can be handled correctly by `echo` (eg: As a single line of information)

`ls | xargs echo` - This will output all the information from `ls` in a single line

**Example 2:**

Let's say I have multiple goLang files inside a folder called go. I would look for them with something like this:

`find go -name *.go -type f | echo` - But if the pipe symbol there and the `echo` at the end, it would not work.

`find go -name *.go -type f | xargs echo` - Here it would work thanks to `xargs` but if I wanted each response from the `find` command in a single line, I would do the following:

`find go -name *.go -type f | xargs -0 echo` - In this case, the same output from `find` would be shown by `echo`.

Commands like `cp, echo, rm, less` and others that need a better way to handle the input get a benefit when used with `xargs`.

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` is used to auto generate command line arguments based (usually) on a list of files.

So considering some alternatives to using the followoing `xargs` command:

```
find . -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'stdlib.h'
```

There are several reasons to use it instead of other options that weren't originally mentioned in other answers:

1. `find . -name '*.c' -exec grep 'stdlib.h' {}\;` will generate one `grep` process for every file—this is generally considered bad practice, and may put a big load on the system if there are many files found.
2. If there are a lot of files, a `grep 'stdlib.h' $(find . -name '*.c')` command will likely fail, because the output of the `$(...)` operation will exceed the maximum command line length of the shell

As mentioned in other answers, the reason for using the `-print0` argument to `find` in this scenario and the `-0` argument to xargs, is so that filenames with certain characters (e.g. quotes, spaces or even newlines) are still handled correctly.